# Axios get dando network error

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, axios

Estou fazendo um curso de react native, mas como meu computador não rodou o Genymotion, tive que improvisar e baixei o BlueStacks para debugar os projetos. O problema é que quando meu programa faz requisições da internet, ele sempre me retorna Network Error. Estou usando o axios.

O erro completo é esse:
[image]

Já procurei em todos os lugares que consegui pensar, mas não achei nada que solucionasse esse problema.

edit: tinha esquecido de colocar o código

main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../services/api';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'JSHunt'
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    loadProducts = async () => {
        const response = await api.get('/products');

        //const { docs } = response.data;

        //console.log(docs);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Página Main</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseUrl: 'https://rocketseat-node.herokuapp.com/api'
});

export default api;
```

Comment: E onde está o código em que você utiliza o AXIOS? Pela mensagem de erro dá a entender que uma exceção está sendo lançada e você não está a capturando, mas não dá para saber sem o seu código.

Comment: Me esqueci de colocar o código, agora editei. Obrigado pelo toque!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro está acontecendo por um erro de sintaxe. Ao se criar uma instancia do AXIOS, você deveria estar usando a propriedade `baseURL`, não `baseUrl`.

Outra melhoria que você poderia fazer no código é adicionar um bloco `try/catch`, pois do jeito que está, quando uma requisição falha, o único erro que você irá receber é que uma exceção foi lançada e não foi capturada, o que não é um feedback muito útil para descobrir a razão do erro.

```
loadProducts = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await api.get('/products');

        //const { docs } = response.data;

        //console.log(docs);

    } catch(err) {
        // TODO
        // adicionar tratamento da exceção
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Tem uns 2 dias que estou procurando o problema, nem acredito que era um errinho de escrita, E também obrigado pela dica, vou implementar no código.